# A light works in one socket but not another. But the socket is functioning

Tags: electrical, led, light

I am using a cord and light recommended by Ikea: the Sunneby cord and Molnart E26 LED bulb.

But after installing it, the light wouldn't turn on. What's happening here?

1. The Molnart E26 works in other light sockets — so it's not the light
2. Other standard E26 bulbs work in the Sunneby socket — so it's not the socket
3. Other E26 bulbs that are like the Molnart (fake incandescent LED effect bulb) do NOT work — so maybe a specific wattage or type of bulb?

I've also pulled out the pad inside the socket out a bit to ensure it makes contact, no change.

Comment: Is there a dimmer controlling the socket?

Comment: There is not, just a regular switch

Comment: I’ll try this next thanks

Comment: @Tetsujin that's completely irrelevant to this situation. "LED light bulbs" are not bare LEDs - they have driver electronics which rectifies the incoming AC to DC and them uses that DC to drive the bare LEDs with a constant current.

Comment: It might help to include a picture of what you're talking about instead of expecting people to go look these products up themselves at the IKEA site. At a minimum, include links to them. Frankly, I'm not sure what "I'm using a cord" means in terms of a light. Is this an extension cord? Does it have a bulb base built into it? that makes little sense to me (as does most IKEA furniture...)

Answer (score 1):

The socket you are trying to screw your lamp into is an Edison base socket, which makes contact at the base of the lamp and passes though the lamp and returns through the outer metal ring of the socket. The contact at the base of the lamp sometimes does not make good contact with the base of the socket.

Sometimes you can use a pair of needle nose pliers and pull that small piece of metal up in order to make sure that it is making proper contact with your new lamp.

Do I need to mention that the power must be off while you are working on the socket?

Be safe and good luck.

Comment: There seem to be two prongs, one on the bottom and one on the side. Do I need to pull both up? But you're right, after removing the shade itself I can tighten it enough to make contact and the light turns on.

Comment: @podcastfan88 sure but just be careful

Comment: some old wiring has the socket live while the lightswitch is off. If I didn't know how my house was wired I wouldn't touch it with pliers without turning off that breaker at minimum and preferably the whole house just to be sure